# Xamarin - Display table

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm a newbie in C#/Xamarin/Android/Mobile development.

I'm calling an API that returns rank, name and budget of a bunch of movies.

I would like to display this data as a table (sort of Excel-like table, no need to have filters):
[image]

I've been investigating and I see there's a [TableLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/table_layout/) form in Xamarin. But I don't think I could get this view with the TableLayout. Is the only possibility to create an HTML/CSS table based on the JSON I get from the API?

I'm also considering [Google Chart's table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table), but I wonder if this is overkill for what I need...

Comment: you want a ListView with multiple columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GridView present in Xamarin or if you want to display them in the type of excel with the features like sorting removing etc you can use the plugins like Syncfusion

Take a look at this link below about the grids in syncfusion which can be used in Xamarin android

http://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-android/sfdatagrid/overview

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For xamarin android you could use Grid Layout. The **[GridLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gridlayout/)** is a new ViewGroup subclass that supports laying out views in a 2D grid, **similar to an HTML table**.

[GridLayoutDemo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/FormsGridLayout/)

[image]

Comment: he is specifically asking about Android - all of your links are for iOS

Comment: @Jason i have changed the link